# Get full page URL with PHP

Tags: php, superglobals

I am trying to get the entire page URL as a string in PHP - so, if the requested URL is `./foo.php?arg1=test&arg2=test2`, I get `"./foo.php?arg1=test&arg2=test2"`.

I know that I can get the `./foo.php` part from `$_SERVER` and the variables from `$_GET`, but I was wondering if there's an easy way to do it in just one fell swoop.

TIA.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the full URL in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I open the following URL in my browser :

```
http://tests/temp/temp.php?a=145&b=glop
```

The following piece of code :

```
var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Gives me :

```
string '/temp/temp.php?a=145&b=glop' (length=27)
```

So, `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` might be what you are looking for...

Answer (score 6):

```
$url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) == 'on' ? 'https' : 'http').'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

This should return the full url based on what was typed in the address bar.

Comment: It is missing a closing paren (after the isset call) and a period before concating the :// but after those changes it does return the full URL.

Answer (score 0):

$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php