# Get the full URL in PHP

Tags: php, url

I use this code to get the full URL:

```
$actual_link = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```

The problem is that I use some masks in my `.htaccess`, so what we see in the URL is not always the real path of the file.

What I need is to get the URL, what is written in the URL, nothing more and nothing less—the full URL.

I need to get how it appears in the Navigation Bar in the web browser, and not the real path of the file on the server.

Comment: For that matter, just have a look at the whole array with `print_r($_SERVER)`, you'll see everything you need there :)

Comment: @Brade URL bar is on the user browser, so why would PHP have any functionalities regarding that? PHP is server side.

Comment: @eis Believe me, there's plenty of reasons to want this. Landing pages that use the same template but need to be tracked separately, etc. And the fact is that PHP (or any server side lang) can return all the various parts of the URL, but never seem to provide the whole thing in one string. It just seems dumb.

Comment: Whole thing is never sent to server side as it shouldn't matter, which is the reason it's not readily available anywhere. I would regard any functionality relying on that broken. But, that's just my opinion.

Comment: The need expressed in the question (full URL, as in the address bar) shadows the actual problem here: if one happens to need the "self URL" of a page on the server (for whatever reason, like filling FORM action URLs), it would certainly be better to get it from the server (e.g. $_SERVER) than trying to assemble it from bits and pieces, in random, bogus manners (as can be frequently seen). That URL would at least be correct, even if only an "effective URL", not necessarily the exact copy of the address bar (which is, indeed, out of the server's reach).

Comment: My example above for the need of a self URL: "filling FORM action URLs" may be wrong, as PHP_SELF (path only, sans domain etc.) should be enough for that. But it doesn't necessarily mean that all other needs for the canonical self URL are invalid. If they indeed are, it would be awesome to see a thorough explanation, why.

Comment: @lunakid it is often convenient to take the current URL, parse it and add some more parameters to it, it would be better if the system was able to generate a canonical URL for every page on it's own, but this is often ridiculously hard to achieve.

Comment: I don't understand why people can't hardcode the full path in the config file itself? It is accessed everywhere in the applications and there are other hardcoded things there, too, like db name, user and pass. Why waste computing power to find out the full path, which can easily be spoofed by sending a different HTTP_HOST?

Comment: One of the reasons why you should not hardcode your URL in config is when you have different platforms where your project will be installed on(dev, integration, production). Each one of them will have their specific URL, and you don't want to change your code according to which server your project is installed on.

Comment: A simpler solution might hopefully come with PHP 7.2+ (proposed version) https://wiki.php.net/rfc/replace_parse_url

Comment: @KaiNoack How would a replacement for [`parse_url(url)`](http://php.net/parse_url) solve the problem of first getting that url?

Answer (score 2518, accepted):

Have a look at `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, i.e.

```
$actual_link = "https://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

(Note that the double quoted string syntax is [perfectly correct](http://php.net/language.types.string#language.types.string.parsing.simple).)

If you want to support both HTTP and HTTPS, you can use

```
$actual_link = (empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'http' : 'https') . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

> ⚠️ This code has **security implications** because the client and the server can set `HTTP_HOST` and `REQUEST_URI` to arbitrary values. It is absolutely necessary to sanitize both values and do proper [input validation](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/20.html) (CWE-20). They must not be used in any security context.

Comment: it just returns the folder, but not the domain name. How do I add the domain name too in this string?

Comment: ok but if the path is ending with a file.. example index.html, it will not work....how do I get the full URL, whatever it is inside the URL..is there a way?

Comment: add the domain name the same way you did it with `$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]` - see my updated answer.

Comment: What if you're on a https link? What if HTTP_HOST is not available or has been tampered with by client side? This answer seems incomplete and unreliable.

Comment: Not much you can do about it, this is the proper method for the question asked.

Comment: this is missing the quotes around the index. should be `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`

Comment: @mattryan it is not - see the "perfectly correct" link (especially the examples) at the end of my answer.

Comment: You can just add the check of HTTPS: `'http' . (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 's' : '') . '://' . "{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}/{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}"`

Comment: If you're outputting the URL to a browser as a link, just leave the http: off.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978235/

Comment: Note that when using ISAPI with IIS, the value `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` will be `off` if the request was not made through the HTTPS protocol.

Comment: Can we not just use `$_SERVER[REQUEST_SCHEME]` instead of setting `http` manually?

Comment: @MatthewT.Baker `$_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME']` is not reliable - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18008135/is-serverrequest-scheme-reliable

Comment: @ax. in regards to your comment on Aug 23 '13, at 17:21. The document which you reference clearly states that your original syntax is incorrect. Here is the pasted information from php.net on the page which you link:

// This is wrong for the same reason as $foo[bar] is wrong  outside a string.
// In other words, it will still work, but only because PHP first looks for a
// constant named foo; an error of level E_NOTICE (undefined constant) will be
// thrown.
echo "This is wrong: {$arr[foo][3]}"; 

Now please stop spreading incorrect information.

Comment: @ax. Please then, enlighten me as to what is syntactically incorrect with this: $var = "http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}"; I see nothing incorrect with that syntax. This however (your syntax): $var = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"; will throw E_NOTICE level errors.

Comment: @Meogi I keep reverting your edits because they are unnecessarily verbose, my version doesn't throw E_NOTICE errors, and this is my answer. Re: "your original syntax is incorrect": You are looking at and quoting the wrong part of the simple string syntax documentation I am referencing. So let me do it for you: `"He drank some $juices[koolaid1] juice."`. Do you see that there are no quotes around the koolaid1? So I will go ahead and revert your edit for the 3rd (and hopefully last) time.

Comment: @Meogi Try this: `error_reporting(-1); $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = 'example.com'; echo "$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]"; // Note that $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST] is enclosed in "s!`

Comment: @ax. Interesting. Well, I meant no disrespect in all this, and it is time to say you were correct. Thank you sir, I have indeed learned something new today. I will leave your post be.

Comment: @ax. And yet, your syntax is discouraged in many places who adopt coding _standards_.  Junior developers shouldn't be encouraged to omit enclosing quotes because it can and _has_ (in my experience) produced bad habits.  That is why coding standards typically say that while you _can_ do a certain thing, it doesn't always mean it's the best or even _good_ practice.  I rest my case saying that in the end, the edited version is still better than your version.

Comment: @mmmshuddup My experience (and i think I have a little more than you) is different. Would you mind to point me to a few of the "coding standards adopted in many places" that discourage my syntax? I think your (and others) misunderstanding is that you think I suggest ommitting quotes and rely on the implicite constant to strings conversion (which throws E_NOTICEs). I _don't_ suggest this - my point is about conciseness _inside_ "-quoted strings, which doesn't require extra '-quotes around `HTTP_HOST`, nor `{}`s (as suggested by your edit) to offset the unneeded extra '-quotes.

Comment: @ax. And you think you have a little more than me? lol ok pal.  If your arrogance wasn't displayed strongly enough by your abuse of the moderator tools in rolling back your answer, it definitely was displayed enough right here; thus discrediting everything else you had to say.  Also, I _didn't_ misunderstand anything (You know what they say about assuming...), I know exactly what you're doing, and it's not good practice.

Comment: @mmmshuddup My assumption about the experience was based on our ages (I am 41), the time we both do programming (I do since 1987), and our stackoverflow history. Feel free to correct me. But please do so with facts, e.g. point me to a few of the "coding standards adopted in many places" that discourage my syntax, give me some concrete arguments why you think your syntax is better - but don't get personal. Thanks!

Comment: These comments from both parties are no longer contributing to the original post, and do not add value. Tooltip on Add Comment states "Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements". Please stick to that.

Comment: wow this answer is terrible - involves unnecessary questionable coding standards, which have nothing to do with the question - and even has crucial bugs. I advise the reader to look at other high scoring answers.

Comment: I wonder why nobody mentioned protocol-relative `//urls`? It solves all issues with http and https

Comment: @vladkras How does `//` solve the issue of putting the complete URL of the current page into an email? Just for starters :)

Comment: This is taking under account server ports:


`$protocol='http' . (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 's' : ''); 
$host="{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}";
$port=(($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != 80 || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != 443) ? "" : ":" . $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']);
$request_uri="{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}";
$server_url= $protocol.'://'.$host.$port.$request_uri;
`

Comment: who has no one mentioned the use of $_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI'] which returns the server uri that is running the php script?

Comment: @Decoded Because `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI']` is [only available when mod_rewrite is enabled](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#EnvVar).

Comment: @webcoder: The `$port` check always outputs null as-is. This is needed:
`$port=($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != 80 && $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != 443) ? ':' . $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] : '';`

Comment: @ax. I don't know if it's still relevant, but since nobody else can answer your coding standards question without getting heated, I will: while your syntax is perfectly valid PHP, many places have coding standards forbidding the use of double-quotes all together, due to their unusual behaviour with edge cases. For example, attempting to de-reference an object works (`"$foo->bar"`), but attempting to de-reference child objects fails (`"$foo->bar->baz"`). You can get similar results from arrays: `"$array[foo]"` works, while `"$array[foo][bar]"` doesn't.

Comment: @ax. It doesn't help that many IDEs and text editors will not perform syntax highlighting (or use different syntax highlighting) on string constants, making it more difficult to find where variables are being used in strings. For this reason, many places (including, for example, the Zend project and the Magento project) will forbid the use of double-quotes in favour of using single-quoted strings with the concatenation operator.

Comment: Whoops, appears I was wrong. Zend framework allows use of double-quotes and variable substitution in the coding standards: https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/coding-standard.coding-style.html

I never saw it done during my time with Magento so I had assumed it was forbidden. My apologies.

Comment: @ivkremer, I think you have a superflous slash in there between `{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}` and `{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}`

Comment: @adamrowe, you're right. That's strange nobody said this before.

Comment: @DoHoaVinh In most cases the browser will not send the #anchor to the server and as such PHP can not display it without help of javascript. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3081862/1276062

Comment: `#` is not necessarily part of http, don't use hashfragment serverside. It's ment to be used in the client only.
Another hint: Properly use `'` and `"`. Only defined constants can be used without quotes => this is wrong: `$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]`. This is good: `$_SERER['HTTP_HOST']`.

Comment: @DanFromGermany `"$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]"`(note the `"`) is NOT wrong - see the "perfectly correct" link and the discussion.

Comment: @ax. its bad practice, 1. dont put variables straight into strings 2. dont treat array keys like constants

Comment: @DanFromGermany 2. `"$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]"` does NOT treat `HTTP_HOST` as constant 1. This is your opinion, and there are other opinions (incl. mine). This has both been said in the comments before (please check). If there are no new arguments (like links to "its bad practice"), please refrain from adding more comments. Thanks!

Comment: `isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']` is not a complete check as it might be `false`

Comment: maybe you need port too: `'http' . (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 's' : '') . '://' . "{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}:{$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}"`

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I am not here to convince anyone to improve his or her coding skills. If you don't want it, don't do it. If your skills pass the average wordpress plugin coder, you will realise conventions and best practice is way more valuable than taking a shortcut by putting a variable straight into double quotes.

Comment: @DanFromGermany - And I'm not advocating for one way or the other. My first comment was: _"or is this simply one of those "you shouldn't" that people keep repeating without actually knowing why"_ and you just came with claims like _"anyone who claims elsewise is really not into enterprise PHP "_ which I wanted some source for. In the lack of proper arguments, I'm marking this down as: _"Some people on internet says this is best practices, for some unknown reason"_. Anyway, this is _very_ off-topic so I'm out...

Comment: @MagnusEriksson This whole Q/A is a good reason not to put variables straight into strings. Look what people come up with, confusing constants and strings: `"http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]"`. Or take this VERY simplified snippet: `$a = '1'; $aa = '2'; echo "$aa";` - does it print 1 or 2? is it readable? Does every IDE get that? Those PHP beginner styles are only OK because the parser tolerates it and tries its best to handle the shitty syntax. Stop claiming I didn't give you reasons not to put vars into strings without `{}` or `" . "` - I already gave you reasons.

Comment: @DanFromGermany - That's because half the people here haven't read up on string expressions at all (and it's hard to understand how things work if you haven't read up on it, best practice or not). Also, that's why you can use `"{$a}a" or "{$aa}"`. That also clears up the "constant" issue, since it would be `"{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}"`, just like outside the string. So, using `{}` will make it clear _and_ readable, but is still "putting a variable in a string".

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I been talking about putting variables straight into strings, where "straight" means without `{}` obv.

Comment: @DanFromGermany - Fair enough, but it wasn't 100% clear from your comment. In my opinion, using `{}` should be good. However, using `"$foo"` is usually OK as well, depending on the context. Like most things in programming, adapt to the context.

Comment: "$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]" The reason this is bad practice is because variables tend to get copy+pasted throughout the lifetime of a code base.  If it gets pasted outside of double quotes then it's introducing a bug.  I would most likely decline a PR that contained this.

Comment: @Mark Roach I would argue that you a) should only copy+paste code you fully understand, b) have a unit test that fails if your (new) code is wrong, and c) educate people about bugs in their PRs.

Comment: Hey, editor. If using HTTP_HOST has security implications then which is the safe way? You don't say.

Comment: shouldn't use double quotes in PHP too often; never on variables coming from a request. injection vulnerability

Comment: `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` is better to use than HTTP_HOST.

Comment: If the answer has security implications, just remove it or changed it.

Comment: check $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'] for https/http

Comment: @MohsenNewtoa As already mentioned above: $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'] is not reliable - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18008135/is-serverrequest-scheme-reliable

Comment: If `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is not available, try `getenv("REQUEST_URI")`, works with Apache 2.

Comment: I have written a helper function around @ax. approach
https://gist.github.com/ahmu83/f33db179eaf7dce273471053017a285a

Comment: @DanielW. *its bad practice, 1. dont put variables straight into strings 2. dont treat array keys like constants* you're welcome to write your own, verbose answer to the question. Personally, I can't imagine why sifting through fewer characters and operators would be any more complicated or confusing (or bad practice for that matter) than sifting through more.

Comment: @MarkRoach Copy-pasting code without understanding how it works is one of the most dreadful things I could imagine a developer would do in a codebase. Do people not *think* about what they write these days? :( Anyway, I would argue that accounting for people doing something that drastic is futile, and that the person copy-pasting random code snippets should be stopped immediately, as they are the *actual* problem in such a scenario. Avoiding problems rather than fixing them will not get rid of them. It is like duct taping a flesh wound.

Answer (score 485):

### Short version to output link on a webpage

```
$url =  "//{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}";

$escaped_url = htmlspecialchars( $url, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' );
echo '<a href="' . $escaped_url . '">' . $escaped_url . '</a>';
```

Here are some more details about the issues and edge cases of [the //example.com/path/ format](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/)

### Full version

```
function url_origin( $s, $use_forwarded_host = false )
{
    $ssl      = ( ! empty( $s['HTTPS'] ) && $s['HTTPS'] == 'on' );
    $sp       = strtolower( $s['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] );
    $protocol = substr( $sp, 0, strpos( $sp, '/' ) ) . ( ( $ssl ) ? 's' : '' );
    $port     = $s['SERVER_PORT'];
    $port     = ( ( ! $ssl && $port=='80' ) || ( $ssl && $port=='443' ) ) ? '' : ':'.$port;
    $host     = ( $use_forwarded_host && isset( $s['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'] ) ) ? $s['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'] : ( isset( $s['HTTP_HOST'] ) ? $s['HTTP_HOST'] : null );
    $host     = isset( $host ) ? $host : $s['SERVER_NAME'] . $port;
    return $protocol . '://' . $host;
}

function full_url( $s, $use_forwarded_host = false )
{
    return url_origin( $s, $use_forwarded_host ) . $s['REQUEST_URI'];
}

$absolute_url = full_url( $_SERVER );
echo $absolute_url;
```

This is a heavily modified version of http://snipplr.com/view.php?codeview&id=2734 (Which no longer exists)

### URL structure:

scheme://**username:password**@domain:port/path?query_string#**fragment_id**

The parts in bold will not be included by the function

### Notes:

- This function does not include `username:password` from a full URL or the fragment (hash).
- It will not show the default port 80 for HTTP and port 443 for HTTPS.
- Only tested with http and https schemes.
- The `#fragment_id` is not sent to the server by the client (browser) and will not be added to the full URL.
- `$_GET` will only contain `foo=bar2` for an URL like `/example?foo=bar1&foo=bar2`.
- Some CMS's and environments will rewrite `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and return `/example?foo=bar2` for an URL like `/example?foo=bar1&foo=bar2`, use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` in this case.
- Keep in mind that an [URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator) = `URL + URN`, but due to popular use, URL now means both URI and URL.
- You should remove `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST` if you do not plan to use proxies or balancers.
- The [spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.23) says that the `Host` header must contain the port number unless it is the default number.

### Client (Browser) controlled variables:

- `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. Any unsupported characters are encoded by the browser before they are sent.
- `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` and is not always available according to comments in the PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php
- `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST']` gets set by balancers and is not mentioned in the list of `$_SERVER` variables in the PHP manual.

### Server controlled variables:

- `$_SERVER['HTTPS']`. The client chooses to use this, but the server returns the actual value of either empty or "on".
- `$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']`. The server only accepts allowed numbers as ports.
- `$_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']`. The server only accepts certain protocols.
- `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` . It is set manually in the server configuration and is not available for IPv6 according to [kralyk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/786102/kralyk).

### Related:

[What is the difference between HTTP_HOST and SERVER_NAME in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297403/http-host-vs-server-name)
[Is Port Number Required in HTTP "Host" Header Parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364144/is-port-number-required-in-http-host-header-parameter)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28049503/175071

Comment: This code will fail if the server is given by IPv6 IP address. To fix that, replace SERVER_NAME with HTTP_HOST.

Comment: note: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` will show `/example?foo=bar2` for url like `/example?foo=bar1&foo=bar2`

Comment: This would not contain anything defined after a #, those aren't passed  through to the server

Comment: `SERVER_NAME` doesn't work well with balancers. Should try `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST`, `HTTP_HOST`, and then fall back to `SERVER_NAME`.

Comment: @Mark shouldn't it be `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SERVER']` instead of `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`? Why is `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST']` better?

Comment: @TimoHuovinen: I think that will give you the name of the balancer rather than the domain name, which is what you're really after. Further, the port will cause it to show :443 on HTTPS, which you probably don't want either.

Comment: Note: according to my tests `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` now correctly returns `/example?foo=bar1&foo=bar2` or url `/example?foo=bar1&foo=bar2` on php 5.4.7, I am now unsure on when exactly it replaced the duplicate key query param. Adding details into the answer.

Comment: I'm unsure if that is no security risk. In your example you can send the Host header to reach the correct page but might let the page think it is called via another host using the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST header. When the application uses this information (for whatever) it can be indeed a security problem as it allows you to promise something what isn't the case.

Comment: @hek2mgl isn't that only insecure for a client that is connecting through an insecure proxy? Still trying to wrap my head around what exactly is insecure about it and how to work with balancers and still keep it secure (if at all possible).

Comment: It doesn't count if you are using HTTP or HTTPS. The - untrusted - user can set this header like he wants. However, using HTTPS would prevent man in the middle attackers from injecting the header

Comment: You normaly accept forwarded-for headers only if the request originates from the ip of the load-balancer/proxy.

Comment: It returns http://localhost:8888:8888 because the port is already set in $s['HTTP_HOST'].

Comment: @Matt3o12 The value of the port is taken directly from the `Host` header, haven't seen it set like that, thanks for mentioning it, will add it as a tweak

Comment: Why does it attempt to use `HTTP_HOST`? Isn't it safer and effectively equivalent to use always `$s['SERVER_NAME'] . $port`?

Comment: @AndréNeves because the function gets the _requested_ URL, while `SERVER_NAME` is simply a setting on the server. Basically the entire thing is user input of sorts.

Comment: Thanks, Timo. I assume then the server could hardly be exploited in this manner, since the exploitable header (`HTTP_HOST`) will be used merely to construct strings to be sent back to the client, is that right?

Comment: @AndréNeves it could be used for more than that, for example to figure out routing, requested environments, etc. One difference could be when two domains point to the same server, then the server will see which one was requested, but it can only be these two hosts, unsupported hosts simply don't connect to the server.

Comment: For me it worked like `$url =  $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`

Comment: @TimoHuovinen I found your answer while Googling for *"`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` php does not work with microsoft edge"* where I noticed the word "edge" being added in this revision http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8891890/27 where I was under the impression it was "Microsoft Edge-related" and unsure if it has anything to do with a serverside `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` coming back as "false" but fine on other browsers, wondering if that has anything to do with it. A more intense Google search did not render any results; am thinking of posting a question about this.

Comment: @Fred-ii- the REQUEST_URI variable is sent by the browser, if microsoft edge does not send it then it won't be available, the question is how do you determine what page you are looking at if you don't get it? The SERVER_NAME variable is set in the server settings by the admin and is usually the name (domain) of the website. I also read that UTF-8 in the settings or the url may affect this.

Comment: @TimoHuovinen Thanks for the response. What you said makes sense, however it's hard to know why Edge failed on that. My friend who informed me of this yesterday as to what I wrote failed on him (on Edge) using `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, had him try another version by replacing `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` with `www.example.com` worked. I.e.: `$host = "www.example.com" . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
if(
($host == "www.example.com" . '/folder/file.php?q=123')
||
($host == "www.example.com" . '/folder/file.php?q=12345'))`, baffling huh? Would you suggest I post a question?

Comment: @TimoHuovinen Addendum to the above. In using the original `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` for an older version with an `<iframe>` and using a form with a post method also did work (on Edge), which I find to be equally baffling. Same code, but different fetching method (with 2 inputs for 2 different queries).

Comment: This code will fail if URL contains `#` character

Comment: @joseantgv What do you mean? Anything past and including the `#` character is not sent to the server by the browser.

Comment: @TimoHuovinen @WilliamKing

In fact the value of the # part is actually sent to the server, and certainly can be accessed by PHP. 

Try echo this: `parse_url($url)['fragment']`

Comment: @MMJ whether it's sent or not depends on the client used. Per http spec it should not be sent as far as I know,  it would be very kind of you if you found the link to the specification, here's the wiki article which also says that it's normally not sent: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_fragment

Comment: Ouch... sorry dude, you are correct. In fact (as [http spec][1] rules) the fragment is not sent to the client. 
I just ran 1 test, informing a string directly in the parse_url() function, like this: `print_r(parse_url('http://localhost:8020/api/endpoint/?abc=123&def=true#hashtag'))` and in this forced and incorrect example, the fragment will exist on the server side.  


  [1]: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396#section-4.1

Answer (score 283):

Examples for:  **`https://www.site.xyz/fold/my.php?var=bla#555`**

> Notice 1:
>
> - the hashtag `#` part was added manually in below php example snippet only for theoretical & illustrational purposes, however Server-Side languages (including PHP) are unable to detect them, because hashtags parts are only recognized in Client-Side browser/javascript...*
>
> Notice 2:
>
> - `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` returns `\` for Windows-OS, while UNIX returns `/`.

```
========== PATHINFO (use for filepathes, not urls) ==========

$x = PATHINFO ($url);
$x['dirname']               https://www.site.xyz/fold
$x['basename']                                        my.php?var=bla#555 // unsafe!
$x['extension']                                          php?var=bla#555 // unsafe!
$x['filename']                                        my

========== PARSE_URL (use for urls, not filepathes) ==========

$x = PARSE_URL ($url);
$x['scheme']                https
$x['host']                          www.site.xyz
$x['path']                                      /fold/my.php
$x['query']                                                  var=bla
$x['fragment']                                                       555
```

**Global variable $_SERVER**

```
$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]   /home/user/public_html
$_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"]     143.34.112.23
$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]     80 (or 443, etc..)
$_SERVER["REQUEST_SCHEME"]  https                           
$_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] <same>
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']              www.site.xyz
$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]               <same>
$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]                        /fold/my.php?var=bla
$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]                                    var=bla

__FILE__                    /home/user/public_html/fold/my.php
$_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"] <same>                              // Note! it will show entry file's path, if `my.php` is not called directly.
__DIR__                     /home/user/public_html/fold
dirname(__FILE__)           <same>
$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]                           /fold/my.php?var=bla  // Note! it will show entry file's path, if `my.php` is not called directly.
parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], PHP_URL_PATH)  /fold/my.php
$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]                              /fold/my.php  // Note! it will show entry file's path, if `my.php` is not called directly.
// detect https
$is_HTTPS = ((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS']!=='off') || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']==443);            //in some cases, you need to add this condition too: if ('https'==$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'])
```

**PHP Functions**

```
dirname($url)               https://www.site.xyz/fold/
basename($url)                                        my.php
debug_backtrace()           SHOWS FULL TRACE OF ALL INCLUDED FILES
```

---

## < For WordPress >

```
// (Let's say, if WordPress is installed in subdirectory:  http://site.xyz/sub/)
home_url()                       http://site.xyz/sub/        // If is_ssl() is true, then it will be "https"
get_stylesheet_directory_uri()   http://site.xyz/sub/wp-content/themes/THEME_NAME  [same: get_bloginfo('template_url') ]
get_stylesheet_directory()       /home/user/public_html/sub/wp-content/themes/THEME_NAME
plugin_dir_url(__FILE__)         http://site.xyz/sub/wp-content/themes/PLUGIN_NAME
plugin_dir_path(__FILE__)        /home/user/public_html/sub/wp-content/plugins/PLUGIN_NAME/
```

Comment: Where is the # part, Is there no way we can access part after # on the server side?

Comment: @RohitKhatri that part is only accessible in the browser and is not sent to server

Comment: What is the wordpress function to get the url with query string too ?

Comment: WARN: `pathinfo()` does not behave with more complex `URL`'s as you would expect - although `/` character is not strictly forbidden in parameters (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455578/characters-allowed-in-get-parameter), parsing such URL will not give you script basename/filename. Try `print_r(pathinfo("https://example.com/subFolder/myfile.php?var=path/to/another/file.png"));`

Comment: For me, I had to do `basename ($_SERVER["PHP_https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-phpSELF"] )` to get the main script name without query string (I need it for the main script  in the sidebar links list)

Answer (score 71):

Here's a solution using a [ternary statement](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary), keeping the code minimal:

```
$url = "http" . (($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) ? "s" : "") . "://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

This is the smallest and easiest way to do this, assuming one's web server is using the standard port 443 for [HTTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure).

Comment: Or use `$_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on"` to check if SSL is on.

Comment: You should be using $_SERVER["HTTPS"] because port 443 is only the default SSL port, not an SSL indicator.

Comment: @AlexBarker - That's why I said "assuming one's web server is using the standard Port 443 for HTTPS."

Answer (score 48):

My favorite cross platform method for finding the current URL is:

```
$url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

Comment: Close, but I needed to change it to this:
$url = ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off') ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

Answer (score 38):

Simply use:

```
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'] . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

Comment: As much as I want to use this, it doesn't work in IIS. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18008135/is-serverrequest-scheme-reliable

Comment: What does it output?

Comment: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: REQUEST_SCHEME

Comment: i love this solution ! but can you also make it work for nginx ?

Comment: `http://example.com` **`:8080`** `/request.php` and fail. These answers are complicated for a reason.

Answer (score 24):

```
function full_path()
{
    $s = &$_SERVER;
    $ssl = (!empty($s['HTTPS']) && $s['HTTPS'] == 'on') ? true:false;
    $sp = strtolower($s['SERVER_PROTOCOL']);
    $protocol = substr($sp, 0, strpos($sp, '/')) . (($ssl) ? 's' : '');
    $port = $s['SERVER_PORT'];
    $port = ((!$ssl && $port=='80') || ($ssl && $port=='443')) ? '' : ':'.$port;
    $host = isset($s['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST']) ? $s['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'] : (isset($s['HTTP_HOST']) ? $s['HTTP_HOST'] : null);
    $host = isset($host) ? $host : $s['SERVER_NAME'] . $port;
    $uri = $protocol . '://' . $host . $s['REQUEST_URI'];
    $segments = explode('?', $uri, 2);
    $url = $segments[0];
    return $url;
}
```

Note: I just made an update to [Timo Huovinen's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8891890/209139), so you won't get any GET parameters in the URL. This URL is plain and removes things like `?hi=i&am=a&get`.

Example:

```
http://www.example.com/index?get=information
```

will be shown as:

```
http://www.example.com/index
```

This is fine unless you use GET paramaters to define some specific content, in which case you should use his code! :-)

Comment: hey thats, pretty cool :) you could also remove anything after a hash "#" (url fragment) in case it somehow slips in

Comment: Not really, because if you set in " explode('#',$segment[0]) ", it will count as error, because " # " the symbol breaks the URL, and can only be read by Javascript.

But what you can do, to be sure, is that you can remake the " return $url; " with " return trim($url,'#'); ", because then you will remove it, in case it will be there. But it will not remove the following content.

You can read up on "Parse_url" if you want to. :-)

Answer (score 20):

Same technique as the accepted answer, but with [HTTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure) support, and more readable:

```
$current_url = sprintf(
    '%s://%s/%s',
    isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https' : 'http',
    $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
);
```

The above gives unwanted slashes.  On my setup **Request_URI** has leading and trailing slashes.  This works better for me.

```
$Current_Url = sprintf(
   '%s://%s/%s',
   isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https' : 'http',
   $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
   trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/\\')
);
```

Comment: This is the simplest and cleanest one and it works.

Comment: Points for readability, thanks.

Answer (score 19):

Clear code, working in all webservers (Apache, nginx, IIS, ...):

```
$url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off' ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Answer (score 17):

> HTTP_HOST and REQUEST_URI must be in quotes, otherwise it throws an error in PHP 7.2

Use:

```
$actual_link = 'https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

If you want to support both HTTP and HTTPS:

```
$actual_link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https' : 'http').'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

⚠️ Using this code has **security implications** because the client can set `HTTP_HOST` and `REQUEST_URI` to arbitrary values. It is absolutely necessary to sanitize both values and do input validation.

Having said this, it is best to determine the link server side without relying on the URL of the browser.

Answer (score 12):

Here is my solution - code is inspired by [Tracy Debugger](https://github.com/nette/tracy/blob/master/src/Tracy/Debugger.php). It was changed for supporting different server ports. You can get full current URL including `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` or just the basic server URL. Check my function:

```
function getCurrentUrl($full = true) {
    if (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
        $parse = parse_url(
            (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && strcasecmp($_SERVER['HTTPS'], 'off') ? 'https://' : 'http://') .
            (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : (isset($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) ? $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] : '')) . (($full) ? $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : null)
        );
        $parse['port'] = $_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]; // Setup protocol for sure (80 is default)
        return http_build_url('', $parse);
    }
}
```

Here is test code:

```
// Follow $_SERVER variables was set only for test
$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'off'; // on
$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] = '9999'; // Setup
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = 'some.crazy.server.5.name:8088'; // Port is optional there
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = '/150/tail/single/normal?get=param';

echo getCurrentUrl();
// http://some.crazy.server.5.name:9999/150/tail/single/normal?get=param

echo getCurrentUrl(false);
// http://some.crazy.server.5.name:9999/
```

Comment: Notice: `http_build_url` requires pecl_http installed

Answer (score 8):

I've made this function to handle the URL:

```
 <?php
     function curPageURL()
     {
         $pageURL = 'http';
         if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
         $pageURL .= "://";
         if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
             $pageURL .=
             $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
         }
         else {
             $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
         }
         return $pageURL;
     }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 7):

This is quite easy to do with your Apache environment variables. This only works with Apache 2, which I assume you are using.

Simply use the following PHP code:

```
<?php
    $request_url = apache_getenv("HTTP_HOST") . apache_getenv("REQUEST_URI");
    echo $request_url;
?>
```

Comment: I tried this 
 $actual_link = 'http' . (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 's' : '') . '://' . "{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}";

Answer (score 7):

This is the solution for your problem:

```
//Fetch page URL by this

$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
echo "$url<br />";

//It will print
//fetch host by this

$host=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
echo "$host<br />";

//You can fetch the full URL by this

$fullurl = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
echo $fullurl;
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
print_r($_SERVER);
```

`$_SERVER` is an array containing information such as headers, paths, and script locations. The entries in this array are created by the web server. There is no guarantee that every web server will provide any of these; servers may omit some, or provide others not listed here. That said, a large number of these variables are accounted for in the » CGI/1.1 specification, so you should be able to expect those.

`$HTTP_SERVER_VARS` contains the same initial information, but is not a superglobal. (Note that `$HTTP_SERVER_VARS` and `$_SERVER` are different variables and that PHP handles them as such)

Answer (score 6):

You can use [http_build_url](http://php.net/http_build_url) with no arguments to get the full [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator) of the current page:

```
$url = http_build_url();
```

Comment: Note that http_build_url() is a PECL function only: (PECL pecl_http >= 0.21.0)

Answer (score 6):

Use this one-liner to find the parent folder URL (if you have no access to http_build_url() that comes along with pecl_http):

```
$url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https://' : 'http://').$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
```

Comment: you mix url and file absolute location on disk

Answer (score 4):

Here is the basis of a more secure version of the accepted answer, using PHP's [filter_input](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) function, which also makes up for the potential lack of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`:

```
$protocol_https = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'HTTPS', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$host = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'HTTP_HOST', FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$request_uri = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_URI', FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
if(strlen($request_uri) == 0)
{
    $request_uri = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'SCRIPT_NAME', FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
    $query_string = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'QUERY_STRING', FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
    if($query_string)
    {
        $request_uri .= '?' . $query_string;
    }
}
$full_url = ($protocol_https ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $host . $request_uri;
```

You could use some different [filters](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php) to tweak it to your liking.

Answer (score 4):

```php
    public static function getCurrentUrl($withQuery = true)
    {
        $protocol = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']) !== 'off')
        or (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) === 'https')
        or (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_FRONT_END_HTTPS']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_FRONT_END_HTTPS']) !== 'off')
        or (isset($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']) && intval($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']) === 443) ? 'https' : 'http';

        $uri = $protocol . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

        return $withQuery ? $uri : str_replace('?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], '', $uri);
    }
```

Comment: Seems to work nicely but I had to replace the `or`s with `||`

Answer (score 3):

I used this statement.

```
$base = "http://$_SERVER[SERVER_NAME]:$_SERVER[SERVER_PORT]$my_web_base_path";
$url = $base . "/" . dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
```

Answer (score 3):

I have used the below code, and it is working fine for me, for both cases, HTTP and HTTPS.

```
function curPageURL() {
  if(isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) && !empty($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) && ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] != 'on' )) {
        $url = 'https://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];//https url
  }  else {
    $url =  'http://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];//http url
  }
  if(( $_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != 80 )) {
     $url .= $_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"];
  }
  $url .= $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
  return $url;
}

echo curPageURL();
```

[Demo](http://thecodedeveloper.com/demo/get-the-current-page-url.php)

Comment: interchange position of http and https.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, `$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'off'` will trigger the HTTPS path. That doesn't seem right. On the other hand, I don't think the original logic was right either.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
$base_dir = __DIR__; // Absolute path to your installation, ex: /var/www/mywebsite
$doc_root = preg_replace("!{$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']}$!", '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']); # ex: /var/www
$base_url = preg_replace("!^{$doc_root}!", '', $base_dir); # ex: '' or '/mywebsite'
$base_url = str_replace('\\', '/', $base_url);//On Windows
$base_url = str_replace($doc_root, '', $base_url);//On Windows
$protocol = empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'http' : 'https';
$port = $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'];
$disp_port = ($protocol == 'http' && $port == 80 || $protocol == 'https' && $port == 443) ? '' : ":$port";
$domain = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$full_url = "$protocol://{$domain}{$disp_port}{$base_url}"; # Ex: 'http://example.com', 'https://example.com/mywebsite', etc.
```

Source: *[PHP Document Root, Path and URL detection](http://blog.lavoie.sl/2013/02/php-document-root-path-and-url-detection.html)*

Comment: Related: *[Answers entirely copied though properly attributed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/)*

Answer (score 2):

Very simple use:

```
function current_url() {
    $current_url  = ( $_SERVER["HTTPS"] != 'on' ) ? 'http://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] :  'https://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
    $current_url .= ( $_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != 80 ) ? ":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] : "";
    $current_url .= $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

    return $current_url;
}
```

Comment: Hi, given how many answers there already are on this page, could you add a bit of explanation about why this is better than the others, or what it does differently?

Comment: Hi, Indeed there are many solutions and my function is simple, clean and easy to understand.

Comment: ***Completely*** missing the point of  IMSoP's comment...

Answer (score 1):

This works for both HTTP and HTTPS.

```
echo 'http' . (($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') ? 's' : '') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Output something like this.

> https://example.com/user.php?token=3f0d9sickc0flmg8hnsngk5u07&access_level=application

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `HTTP_ORIGIN` as illustrated in the snippet below:

```
if ( ! array_key_exists( 'HTTP_ORIGIN', $_SERVER ) ) {
    $this->referer = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
} else {
    $this->referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'];
}
```

Comment: What is *HTTP_ORIGIN* supposed to do? Why is it necessary?

Comment: OK, the answerer has left the building (*"Last seen more than 4 years ago "*). Perhaps somebody else can chime it?

Answer (score 0):

I think this method is good..try it

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "localhost"){
    define('SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
    define('SITEPATH', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
    define('CSS', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/css/');
    define('IMAGES', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/images/');
}
else{
    define('SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
    define('SITEPATH', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
    define('TEMPLATE', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/incs/template/');
    define('CSS', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/css/');
    define('IMAGES', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/images/');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$page_url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

For more: *[How to get the full URL of a page using PHP](https://codeupweb.wordpress.com/2017/10/11/how-to-get-the-full-url-of-page-using-php/)*

Comment: This answer has been copied from above.

Comment: Yeah, apart from the variable this is identical to https://stackoverflow.com/a/23717829/446106 (at time of writing)